# Browning of the blueberry bush

Tags: blueberries

My husband is noticing that the tips of our blueberry plants are turning brown, it’s not the leaves, but rather the stems. They are in barrels, would that be the cause. They’ve been in barrels about 4 years. Last year they did pretty good. This year they look like they might die. HELP!

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a picture or two? With plants and diagnostics it’s really helpful to see what exactly you are talking about.  You can always [edit] your post. I would also recommend you take the time for the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works.